# Unity ARkit- make AR camera collide with world objects causes crash?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

Building an AR game with Unity ARKit here and I need to create collisions/allow the user, the camera object, to push objects I spawn. I tried to do what I would in a normal game - added a capsule collider/object with rigid body as child of my Ar camera here:

[image]

and had rigidbodies/nontrigger box colliders on my AR game objects. I want my AR camera as the person moves around to be able to push (with their "body") the game objects out of the way.

My approach leads to some infinite loop/something where Unity loads indefinitely. What is wrong here? is this possible?

Comment: Can you post your code which causes this loop so we can help?

Comment: There isn't any code really - just added the rigid bodies as described. Has anyone else gotten this working?